# Scilab inputs & linspace?

Tags: input, scilab

Been having trouble with figuring this one out. This is my first Scilab homework, so I'm still a novice.

Table 1 will convert °F to K

1. Request the user to input the number of elements you want in a vector. Call this variable “Increment1”.
2. Use the linspace function to create a vector from 0°F to 200°F and uses the number of elements input by the user in the following formula (200/”increment1”)+1. Name this variable “F”.
3. Use the formula (5/9)*(F +459.67) to create a vector of K values. Name this variable “K”.
4. Concatenate F and K into a 2 row matrix (such that F values are directly on top of K values). Name this variable “A”.
5. Display A.

I've attached a screenshot of what I've got so far (it's a mod of something I found online), but I'm stuck. Do I have the right idea with the inputs and linspace (parts 1 & 2)?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAMEw.png)

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**I am not sure about how exactly the formula (200/Increment1)+1 is to be used but this is how i understood the question and it gives the desired output**

```
clear
clc
Increment1=input("Enter number of elements:")
F=linspace(0,200,200/Increment1+1)
for n=1:(200/Increment1)+1
    k=(5/9)*(F(n)+459.67)
    K(n)=k   
end
disp("   F         K")
F=F'
A=cat(2,F,K)
disp(A)
```

output-

```
Enter number of elements:100


    F         K

   0.     255.37222
   100.   310.92778
   200.   366.48333
```

Comment: I tried something similar and it was telling me that argument 3 of the linspace portion was not valid because it was expecting an integer. 

This is incredibly helpful though, thank you very much.

Comment: You can avoid  the for loop with K=(5/9)*(F+459.67) as Scilab perform vector computation (and it is much more efficient)

Comment: @RaphaelGranas Indeed. See my answer for an explanation of Rohan error.

Answer (score 0):

In scilab there's two way to define a vector : using the step as in `x=start:step:end` or the total number of element as in `x=linspace(start,end,number)`

So if you wish `Increment1` elements as suggested, you would have to write `F=linspace(0,200,Increment1)`.

Indeed, the step between two element of F is `(end-start)/(number-1)` so you could also write `F=0:200/(Increment1-1):200`. There may be a mistake in your original question as I don't understand mathematically the '200/Increment1+1' part

As said by @user5694329, you should not think with `for` loops but more with linear algebra like `K=(5/9)*(F+459.67)` wich translate to : take the vector F, add 459.67 to each element, and multiply that by 5/9

Also be aware that `x=x'` (as suggested by Rohan) computes the transpose conjugate of a matrix/vector. For real values, it doesn't matter but you may have some troubles in the future if you work with complex number. Use `x=x.'` instead or `x=transpose(x)'`. Finally, if you need a particular shape, it's better to use the matrix function : `x = matrix(x,-1,1)` translates to 'take x, and make it 1 column, and as many row as necessary' (obviously  `x = matrix(x,1,-1)` is the row version). Read the help for further details `help matrix`.

The complete answer is (that makes sense to me)

```
clear;
clc;
// 1.Request the user to input the number of elements you want in a vector. 
// Call this variable “Increment1”. 
Increment1=input("Enter number of elements:");

// Use the linspace function to create a vector from 0°F to 200°F. Name this variable “F”. 
F=linspace(0,200,Increment1) // or F=0:200/(Increment1-1):200;
// NOT UNDERSTOOD : and uses the number of elements input by the user in the following formula (200/”increment1”)+1.

F=matrix(F,1,-1); // BONUS : we assure that F is a row
// Use the formula (5/9)*(F +459.67) to create a vector of K values. Name this variable “K”.  
K=(5/9)*(F+459.67); //  K is also a row since F is
// 4. Concatenate F and K into a 2 row matrix (such that F values are directly on top of K values). Name this variable “A”
A = [F;K] // or cat(1,F,K) : Takes F, change row (;), add K
// Display A
disp(A)
```